# Auto zooming page according to height

Tags: javascript, html, css, zooming

I need help finding way how to auto zoom viewer's browser. My code for example is 710px heigh, but viewer's page would be I dont know like 1000px heigh. Evading body being too small I need a way to autozoom it so it is fullpage. I have it full of absolute pictures so no margins and things like that wont work.. Maybe finding out his resolution and convert to zoom neccecary and than zoom it to that? My page http://www.linbach.cz . There are still some other problem but already fixed em just didnt upload it yet so just need this.. Big big please help

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Yeah so when I zoom it to 110%, thats what I want to get in my sreen case, but others would see it wrong if they dont have same display, right..

Comment: <http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?248705-Page-auto-zoom-script-to-fit-with-no-scrollbars> this dudes code didnt work for me, but does it

Comment: use this as a reference: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

Comment: Sorry but i believe icluding code wont help anyone in this case rather than link.